# Using the Temperature Sensor TC1047A with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc

In the manual in order to convert the A/D conversion result of an HCS12 MCU to the corresponding temperature, we need to do the
following:

1. Divide the conversion result by 6.2
2. Subtract 40 from the quotient

Is there a particular reason for this, or this is a way that temperature sensor is made?

Thanks

Comment: You need to think about the details of the temperature sensor. It presumably outputs x volts / degree C above some minimum temperature? Your A/D then gives y bits per volt. Just work through the maths

Comment: Yes the minimum temperature is -40 so I guess that's where 40 comes from.But 6.2 is a mystery

Comment: It's a 10 bit A/D

Comment: how many bits per volt does the A/D give? (1023 @ 5V?) and how many volts / °C does the sensor give?

Comment: The TC1047A temperature sensor has a 10 mV/C voltage slope

Comment: I guess it should be 1023for 5 volts

Comment: hmm ok, that gives 0.01 * 1023/ 5.0 bits per °C (about 2 bits per °C) - that's not 6.2 - is the temp sensor wired straight into the A2D or is it amplified? Also is your answer in °C or °F ?

Comment: Also the datasheet shows a 0.1V offset at -40°C so the actual output voltage from the temp sensor is: V = (temp+50) * 0.01. So the final result should be -50 not -40. I think your manual may be wrong

Comment: It is not wired to ADC .  There is a scaling circuit in between.

Comment: The temperature sensor has the output voltage from 0.1 to 1.75 for the temperature range of -40 to 125. The range of the voltage connected to the MCU is 0 to 5 v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sensor has an input range of -40°C to +125°C producing a voltage range of 0.1V - 1.75V

There is a scaling circuit which scales and offsets this voltage to 0V @ -40°C to 5V @ 125°C
- that is a 165°C range of temperature over a 5V range in voltage

The A2D produce a reading of 0 for a 0V input and 1023 for 5V input - that is a range of 1024

so 1024 / 165 = 6.206
and a 40°C offset

To convert bits to °C you take the A2D reading divide by 6.206 and subtract 40.